# Error in IE8 Browser -> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In my joomla project(http://crystalwrightlive.com) home page there is one sliding banner section, but this banner not working in IE browser (working fine in FF browser) and showing following error:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Sat, 8 May 2010 06:42:15 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://crystalwrightlive.com/index.php

In index page included a jquery file:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

when i removed this JS file, no error but this JQuery file needed for this sliding banner.

How can i fix this issue, Please anyone help me!!!!

Comment: I'm testing your site in IE8 and cannot reproduce the error. Have you changed something?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all your javascript code at the footer of the page and then see.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail about the functions called, etc. there isn't much I can tell you except that the error description is quite accurate; IE just doesn't support a function required to do something related to that banner (one example why the browser is so poor).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was due to a [`$` mapping conflict.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Using `jQuery` instead of `$` solved the issue.